# alternatives to javascript for tor websites?

Tags: javascript

I am not very experienced with web programming yet, so please excuse this question. I could not find much information about in the web so I decided to ask here.

Tor by default blocks javascript. What other programming languages can I use to have functionality in my website?

For example, donations, buttons etc...

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: > Tor by default blocks javascript. What other programming languages can I use to have functionality in my website?

No, it doesn't. That's an option that you can turn off or on and by default javascript is allowed.

Comment: ok, this is correct. Many users though are blocking javascript for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a popular choice. It runs entirely on the web server, but isn’t as flashy as JS. Like stated in the comment of your question though, JavaScript is not disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question, not Tor-related. JavaScript is **not** an evil if you're properly encapsulating the container that is running your browser. And it's not a Tor Browser developers fault to block them: a browser *is* just an application but you need a virtualization to isolate it properly so they can't do it from the application side. Even more: use Firefox inside a VM and isolate it, so you will have a fully functional websites and anonymity at the same time.